# writing a constraint to enforce a minimum 1 occurence af a value

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to write a check constraint to enforce at least 1 occurence of a value in a a table:

```
DECLARE @Instances INT
SELECT @Instances = COUNT (instructor) FROM Prof_Teach_Courses
SET @Instances =  (SELECT COUNT(instructor) FROM Prof_Teach_Courses)
GO
ALTER TABLE Prof_Teach_Courses
ADD CONSTRAINT count_1_instance CHECK (@Instances >= 1)
GO
```

i am getting an error :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Instances".

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to ask here, if I am honest. The logic you are implementing makes even less sense; a variable only exists in the scope it is defined, and you have 2 batches. The fact you want to use a variable in a `CONSTRAINT` makes even less sense.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because in real world model you should not want to have *some* value in any random row just because it have to be. Such constraint may easily be cheated by any junk value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't solve this with variables you need a function for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Prof_Teach_Courses (col1 int, instructor int);
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION CheckInstructor()  
> RETURNS int  
> AS   
> BEGIN  
>    DECLARE @Instances int  
>    SELECT @Instances = COUNT(instructor) FROM Prof_Teach_Courses 
>    RETURN @Instances  
> END;
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE Prof_Teach_Courses  
> ADD CONSTRAINT count_1_instance CHECK (dbo.CheckInstructor() >= 1 );  
>  
> GO
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f760816aad5a2f867a28d9d13d4d5954)*

Comment: Can you link the resource you're citing here please @nbk?

Comment: i've understood my mistake, i can use the value of COUNT only when it stored in structure.

Comment: yes variables have a local scope and so it has to exist before the check constraint which is not possible